# MVC 3 Razor EditorTemplate / DisplayTemplate master pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Has anyone figured out how to use Master Pages for Editor & DisplayTemplates with Razor similar to what Brad Wilson documented here?

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-5-master-page-templates.html

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This didn't turn out to be as complex as I originally thought.

A little disclaimer: This isn't fully vetted and is a simple example just to get it to work.

This is what i did:

~/Views/Shared/_TemplateMaster.cshtml

```
<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="@ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName">@ViewData.ModelMetadata.GetDisplayName()</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @RenderSection("DataContent")
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ValidationMessage("")
</div>
```

~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_TemplateMaster.cshtml";
}

@section DataContent
{
    @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "" })
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I am not a programmer by profession, but I am a professional "hair tearer-outer", and this saved some of my follicles. :)

Comment: Really good, but you can make it even better by using the HtmlHelper methods instead of ViewData if you replace `<label>...</label>` in your master template with `@Html.LabelForModel()` and `@Html.TextBox...` in your editor template with `@Html.TextBoxForModel()`